# WebStorm compiling TypeScript file in-place instead of generating into target folder

Tags: typescript, webstorm

We are using WebStorm with TypeScript project. We have configured project correctly using tsconfig.json as everything works correctly from command line.

However, when opened the project in WebStorm, it compiles the ts files in place (it generates js file in same folder as corresponding ts file) where as tsconfig says it should be in `dist` dir.

For example, in below screenshot, `evaluator.js` is in same folder as `evaluator.ts` file. Any idea how to configure WebStorm such that it doesn't generate js files in place?

[image]

Here are Typescript preferences.

[image]

Here is the tsconfig.json file

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "pretty": false,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently Webstorm transpiles typescript files to javascript independently](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000098564-Disable-Auto-Transpiling-TS-to-JS)

> Make sure that 'Enable TypeScript compiler' is disabled in Preferences
>   | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, and that you don't have
>   TypeScript file watcher set up in Preferences | Tools | File Watchers

Comment: I don't have any file watcher setup and just posted my typescript preferences. I don't see "Enable Typescript Compiler" option in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this in your `package.json`

```
...
  "main": "app/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "copyjson": "copyfiles 'src/**/*.json' app",
    "copyhbs": "copyfiles 'src/**/*.hbs' app",
    "copyhtml": "copyfiles 'src/**/*.html' app",
    "prebuild": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "build": "tsc && npm run copyjson && npm run copyhbs && npm run copyhtml",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node app/src/index"
  }
...
```

then do a

```
npm install
npm run build
npm run start
```

Comment: I don't think this helps as command line works for me, it is the usage within WebStorm is th eissue.

Comment: hmmm I had the same issue, before I did it like above. now it works perfectly.  have a look at the setup here: https://github.com/joergi/learning-typescript/blob/master/package.json (I use IntelliJ (what means WebStorm...) but i build there on commandline to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However for me the problem was that when I ran my unit tests the newest version of the code was not reflected in the transpiled files. Could not find a way to fix it from webstorms settings. So in the end I just ended up adding a yarn target to remove all of the generated files in source. I can then run this before I run the tests to make sure that I get a freshly transpiled version. The script in package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "clear-cache": "find src -type f \\( -name \"*.js\" -o -name \"*.d.ts.map\" -o -name \"*.d.ts\" \\) -exec rm {} \\;",
  },
```

Doesn't really solved the original problem, but it was as close as I was able to get.